# Helm dependency is false but subchart is deployed anyway

Tags: kubernetes, dependencies, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a Helm/Kubernetes deployment with the following structure:

```
mainchart
|- subchart1
|  |- database
|- subchart2
...
```

So, **database** is a subchart of **subchart1**; no other subchart contains **database**.

In **subchart1**, Chart.yaml says:

```
dependencies:
- name: database
  version: "*"
  condition: global.owndb
```

and Values.yaml says:

```
global:
  owndb: false
```

Also, in **mainchart**, Values.yaml says:

```
global:
  owndb: false
```

When I run "helm install", I supposed the database chart was not deployed. It gets deployed all the times, instead.
Any idea of why it's behaving like this? I'm using **helm v3.6.3**

Comment: Not sure if this is why, but subcharts need to be defined in a folder named "charts" under the main chart, they can't just be in their own folder. You also didn't specify, but your main chart also needs to express a dependency on subchart1.

Comment: @R10t-- maybe I wasn't detailed enough in my description, but yes: my subcharts are in the charts folder and all dependencies are declared in every level. Thank you, anyway